# SQL Server query to retrieve all from View

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL View, similiar to the one below:

```
    map_id  | type_id | path
    1         1         0
    2         2         0
    3         3         0
    4         1         A>B
    5         1         A>B>C
    6         2         T>Z
    7         2         T>Z>X
    8         3         U
    9         3         X>Y  
   10         1         D
```

And another table, tblRoles

```
role_group_id  | type_id  | map_id
1                1          1
2                1          4
```

I want to build a query that will include all `map_id` where `role_group_id` has the `map_id = 1` and for the rest it should only get the corresponding `map_id`

So, the query result should look like:

```
role_group_id  | type_id  | map_id  | path
1                1          4         A>B
1                1          5         A>B>C
1                1          10        D
1                1          1         0
2                1          4         A>B
```

Could someone point me to the correct way?
Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't see the pattern in your expected result

Comment: Basically, in the tblRoles I want to have the liberty of adding a single row for type_id wich will be queried for all rows with same type_id from view.. It's like select all when map_id=1 and if map_id is different, select only the corresponding row from view

Comment: but the question is why `1 1 0` not included in the result? Maybe because it has a path of `0`? It has a type id of 1 and map id of 1

Comment: correct, i will edit the question

Comment: ok it's clearer now

Comment: `2                2          1         A>B` i think this is wrong also, It should be `2  1 4  A > B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this yet, I hope this should work.

```
SELECT r.role_group_id
       ,r.type_id
       ,sv.map_id
       ,sv.path
FROM tblRoles r
LEFT JOIN sampleView sv ON r.type_id = sv.type_id
WHERE r.map_id = 1
UNION
SELECT r.role_group_id
       ,r.type_id
       ,r.map_id
       ,sv.path
FROM tblRoles r
INNER JOIN sampleView sv ON r.map_id = sv.map_id
WHERE r.map_id <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`

> @rosuandreimihai: select all when map_id=1 and if map_id is different, select only the
>   corresponding row

```
DECLARE @CurrentMapId INT = 1

SELECT * FROM FirstTable
WHERE
    TYPE_ID IN 
    (
        SELECT r.type_id FROM tblRoles r
        WHERE           
            map_id = @CurrentMapId
    )
UNION
SELECT * FROM FirstTable
WHERE
    map_id   IN 
    (
        SELECT r.map_id FROM tblRoles r
        WHERE           
            @CurrentMapId = 1 OR
            map_id = @CurrentMapId
    )
```